# Regex needed to capitalize names and have the rest be lowercase and properly handle names like McDonald

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have an application in which the user enters first and last name.  We want the application to convert any name typed in, whether all capitals, or all lower case, or a mixture of the two to first letter capitalized and the rest lower case.  However, if there are spaces, hyphens, or apostrophes in the name, the first letter after them is to be capitalized.

I have the following java script code that handles the above well:

```
name = name.replace(/\b\w+/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
```

However, in addition, we would like to not convert names typed in as "McIntire" or "MacDonald", or "LaToya", or "LeeAnn" to "Mcintire", "Macdonald", "Latoya", or "Latoya" or "Leeann".  The above regex does not do what we want for names like this.  I know that you can't handle every case of legitimate mixing of capital and lower case letters in the middle of a name, but it is common to have the third or fourth letter be capitalized in names.  Therefore, we would like to have java script or regex to not change a capital letter in the third or fourth position to a lower case letter, while still converting the rest as per the above regex and function.  I realize that this would allow people to mix case like JoHn or WilLiam and have it stay like that, but, we can't handle every dumb thing a user might do and we would have to accept things like that.  If we could handle the very common cases of the third or fourth letter being capitalized, that should be sufficient.

So, to summarize, if anyone can supply java script to do what my statement above does, plus not change a third or fourth letter that the user typed in as a capital letter to lowercase, I would be grateful.

Comment: you have posted exemplary words that should not be converted. Post the words that should be converted

Comment: Before you start messing with people's names you should read "[Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)" — also, I know someone with the last name _"Dell'Erba"_ where your "third or fourth" rule would fail.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is not touch the 3rd and 4th characters, then using what you have supplied:

```
name = name.replace(/\b\w+/g, function(txt){
  return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.charAt(1).toLowerCase() +
  txt.substr(2,2) + txt.substr(4).toLowerCase();});
```

That is, make the first letter upper case, the second lowercase, the third and fourth untouched, and from the 5th on, lower cased.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you.  That was so simple and nice, I don't know why I didn't think of it!

Comment: No problem and yeah it sometimes simple nice answers elude us. Please accept the answer if it worked for you.